# render different views in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here, the view will be "test_email.html" as default.

```
def test_email(data)
  notif_type = data['notif_type']
  emails_list = ['132xxy@yahoo.com', '133xxy@yahoo.com']
  subject = case notif_type
  when 'test_case_1'
    "test1"
  when 'test_case_2'
    "test2"
  when 'test_case_3'
    "test3"
  mail(:to => emails_list, :subject => subject) do |format|
    format.html { render  :layout => 'layouts/newdesign' }
  end
end
```

What I want is as follows:
for test_case_3, render "test_case_3.html"
for the rest, render "test_email" as default
How could I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def test_email(data)
  notif_type = data['notif_type']
  emails_list = ['132xxy@yahoo.com', '133xxy@yahoo.com']
  @template = 'test_email'
  subject = case notif_type
    when 'test_case_3'
      @template = 'test_case_3.html'
      "test3"
    when 'test_case_1'
      "test1"
    when 'test_case_2'
      "test2"
    end
  mail(:to => emails_list, :subject => subject) do |format|
      format.html {render template: @template, :layout => 'layouts/newdesign' }
  end
end
```